# WP_Query not ordering correctly

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, custom-field, query, rest-api

I have two custom user meta fields created with ACF. One is `quantidade_corretas_dia_4` (Numeric, integer) and another `tempo_dia_4` (Numeric, decimal). I am using WP_User_Query to get users ordered by both this values like this:

```php
    $args = array(
        "fields" => "ids",
        "number" => -1,
        "meta_query" => array(
        
            "relation" => "AND",
            "query_one" => array(
                "type" => "NUMERIC",
                "key" => "quantidade_corretas_dia_4"
            ),
            "query_two" => array(
                "type" => "DECIMAL",
                "key" => "tempo_dia_4"
            ),
        ),
        "orderby" => array(
            "query_one" => "DESC",
            "query_two" => "ASC"
        ),

    );

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

    $users = $user_query->get_results();
```

However, i cannot understand why my results are being ordered by `quantidade_corretas_dia_4` but not by `tempo_dia_4`. Here is an example of what i get:

[image]

I expected user with ID 44 to be placed before user with ID 65, since they have same `quantidade_corretas_dia_4` but `tempo_dia_4` is different (lesser in ID 44 than ID 65).

What am i doing wrong in this query?

Thanks.

Comment: possibly related: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/#comment-2182

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell, i've seen some people complaining about the way WP casts values to query in the mysql database. However, i cannot confirm that this is the problem with decimal values.